# Set progressbar indeterminate srcCompat

Tags: java, android, drawable

I make my own progressBar so i can tint the color in pre-lolipop and it worked well until i change the drawable from png into vector. I get long stacktrace error. As what i search on google, the error is because i use src instead of srcCompat. But i didn't find any way to use srcCompat in indeterminate drawable of progressBar. So please could you tell me how to use srcCompat to my indeterminate?

XML :

```
<com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.helper.view.TintProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/xml_progress_bar_circle"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"/>
```

xml_progress_bar_circle :

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_progress_bar"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
```

ic_progress_bar :

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="80.433334"
    android:viewportWidth="80.433334" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.18" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M75.21,40.22A34.99,34.99 0,0 1,53.61 72.55,34.99 34.99,0 0,1 15.47,64.96 34.99,34.99 0,0 1,7.89 26.83,34.99 34.99,0 0,1 40.22,5.23"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.99" android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="8.37210464"/>
</vector>
```

**ERROR** :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal, PID: 18996
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal/com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.ActivityRegister}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.helper.view.TintProgressBar
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.helper.view.TintProgressBar
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.BaseActivity_Network.onCreate(BaseActivity_Network.kt:37)
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.ActivityRegister.onCreate(ActivityRegister.kt:73)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.BaseActivity_Network.onCreate(BaseActivity_Network.kt:37) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.ActivityRegister.onCreate(ActivityRegister.kt:73) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/xml_progress_bar_circle.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070090
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2163)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2082)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:294)
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:246)
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:242)
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.helper.view.TintProgressBar.<init>(TintProgressBar.kt:23)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.BaseActivity_Network.onCreate(BaseActivity_Network.kt:37) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.ActivityRegister.onCreate(ActivityRegister.kt:73) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_progress_bar.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07007d
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2163)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2082)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:706)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable.inflate(RotateDrawable.java:247)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2159)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2082) 
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:294) 
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:246) 
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:242) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.helper.view.TintProgressBar.<init>(TintProgressBar.kt:23) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.BaseActivity_Network.onCreate(BaseActivity_Network.kt:37) 
    at com.muadzbinjabal.muadzbinjabal.ActivityRegister.onCreate(ActivityRegister.kt:73) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: invalid drawable t
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the srcCompat you have to use it following

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"
```

Add this to the top parent view.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: to change indeterminate drawable then we've to write `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/xml_progress_bar_circle"`.. Then how to use srcCompat to indeterminateDrawable?